# Classical axioms implies every proposition is decidable?

Tags: coq

In the Lean manual 'Theorem proving in Lean' I read:
"With the classical axioms, we can prove that every proposition is decidable".

I would like to seek clarification about this statement and I am asking a Coq forum, as the question applies as much to Coq as it does to Lean (but feeling I am more likely to get an answer here).

When reading "With the classical axioms", I understand that we have something equivalent to the law of excluded middle:

```
Axiom LEM : forall (p:Prop), p \/ ~p.
```

When reading "every proposition is decidable", I understand that we can define a function (or at least we can prove the existence of such a function):

```
Definition decide (p:Prop) : Dec p.
```

where `Dec` is the inductive type family:

```
Inductive Dec (p:Prop) : Type :=
| isFalse : ~p -> Dec p
| isTrue  :  p -> Dec p
.
```

Yet, with what I know of Coq, I cannot implement `decide` as I cannot destruct `(LEM p)` (of sort `Prop`) to return something other than a `Prop`.

So my question is: assuming there is no mistake and the statement "With the classical axioms, we can prove that every proposition is decidable" is justified, I would like to know how I should understand it so I get out of the paradox I have highlighted. Is it maybe that we can prove the existence of the function `decide` (using `LEM`) but cannot actually provide a witness of this existence?

Comment: Lean actually assumes [a much stronger axiom](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/axioms_and_computation.html#choice) that *would* allow you to prove this.

Comment: @SCappella, ok I have not yet reached this part of the book yet (I am almost there) so I trust I ll understand when I reach it. Thanks v much for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the calculus of constructions without any axioms, there is *meta-theoretical* property that every proof of `A \/ B` is necessarily a proof that `A` holds (packaged using the constructor `or_introl`) or a proof that `B` holds (using the other constructor).  So a proof of `A \/ ~ A` is either a proof that `A` holds or a proof that `~ A` holds.

Following this meta-theoretical property, in **Coq without any axioms**, all proofs of propositions of the form `forall x, P x \/ ~P x` actually are proofs that `P` is decidable.  In this paragraph, the meaning of *decidable* is the commonly accepted meaning, as used by computability books.

Some users started using the word *decidable* for any predicate `P` so that there exists a proof of `forall x, P x \/ ~ P x`.  But they are actually talking about a different thing.  To make it clearer, I will call this notion *abuse-of-terminology-decidable*.

Now, if you add an axiom like LEM in Coq, you basically state that every predicate `P` becomes *abuse-of-terminology-decidable*.  Of course, you cannot change the meaning of *conventionally-decidable* by just adding an axiom in you Coq development, so there is no inclusion anymore.

I have been fighting against this abuse of terminology for years, but without success.

To be more precise, in Coq terminology, the term decidable is not used for propositions or predicates that enjoy LEM, but for propositions or predicates that enjoy the stronger following statement:

```
forall x, {P x}+{~P x}
```

Proofs of such propositions are often named with `_dec` suffix, where `_dec` directly refers to *decidable*.  This abuse is less strong, but it is still an abuse of terminology.

Comment: Do you mean external vs internal decidability in the terminology of nLab? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/decidable+proposition (sect. 1)

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Yves !

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @AntonTrunov.  No, I think there is an extra difference between "externally decidable" and "decidable in the common sense".  In the article you point to, "externally decidable" is a notion that is relative to a given theory.  But when we say that the halting problem is undecidable, we use the word "undecidable" in a sense that is stronger and refers to the existence of an algorithm taking inputs (programs in the case of the halting problem), terminating for all inputs, deciding for each input whether the property (the program halts) holds or not.